# What is this optical illusion in which airplane propellers appear to rotate backwards? How is it explained?

Tags: optics, perception

[image: Airplane's propellers are rotating anti-clockwise, but seen as they are rotating clockwise.]

This airplane's propellers are both rotating anti-clockwise. But as you see, they are seem like rotating clockwise seen from front (nose) side. This phenomenon is known as optical illusion.

My question is, how to explain it? This occurs at certain rotation speed only. When the rotation is put slower, we will see the actual rotation, so does when it put higher. Need to know the range of rotation speed when it will be seen revert the rotation.

Comment: @JohnRennie Perhaps what needs to be added to an explanation is the reason for the image of the propeller blades being curved?

Comment: I added. I have asked the.frequency range when it will be seen revert the rotation.

Comment: Title covers a broader range of phenomena. You should focus on wheel effect.

Comment: Based on the way that the camera is looking at the propellers, it is taking discrete pictures every 1/24 of a second.  Due to this, the camera system is a sampled data system.  If some phenomenon is occurring at a frequency that is substantially higher than 1/2 of the sampling frequency, you will see an effect known as aliasing.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Answer (score 4):

The core of this question is a complete duplicate of [When does the wagon-wheel effect occur?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/155778/when-does-the-wagon-wheel-effect-occur), so there's nothing much to add to that, but it's important to comment on this part of the question:

> But as you see, they are seem like rotating clockwise seen from front (nose) side.

It's important to note that what's shown in the picture has **nothing** to do with what you experienced visually at the time the picture was taken. There is no way to infer from the camera-taken picture what the propeller looked like visually, or what way it appeared to be moving.

Instead, the curve in the propeller blade (which would *not* have been visually observable) is a rolling-shutter effect, caused by the fact that the data is recorded from the CCD to the camera's memory in a sequential scanning fashion instead of in one fell swoop. This is explained in detail by Smarter Every Day in [Rolling Shutter Explained (Why Do Cameras Do This?)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dNVtMmLlnoE) and by Matt Parker on [Rolling Shutter Explained on the Cheap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nP1elMR5qjc) at standupmaths.

Comment: There is certain rotation speed that the "reverse" rotation will occurs. Below and above that rotation speed (or sometimes it said as frequency), it will show the correct rotation's direction. Then, the question is, what is that frequency? In that link you claimed have been explained, there is no actual or definitive explanation. Even the asker was not satisfied by all the answer so he didn't accept one of them. And specifically, there is certain frequency which the phenomenon occurs. Below and above, that will show the correct direction.

Comment: @AirCraftLover All of that is explained in depth in [the Wikipedia page for the wagon-wheel effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagon-wheel_effect). If you've read it carefully and in full, and you have *specific* questions about it, you should edit your question to be very clear about them.

Comment: There's also [this Photo.SE post](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/9523) that covers the rolling-shutter effect pretty nicely.